# How to fix the apktool recompiling errors?

Tags: apktool

I tried to decompile my apk using the apktool and it worked without any errors but when i tried to recompile it, it showed a lot of errors. What should I do?
Below is what i entered and what the result was..

```
C:\New folder>apktool b talalkhan
I: Using Apktool 2.4.0
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether resources has changed...
I: Building resources...
W: C:\New folder\talalkhan\res\layout-v26\abc_screen_toolbar.xml:5: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'keyboardNavigationCluster' in package 'android'
W:
W: C:\New folder\talalkhan\res\layout\layout_listitem.xml:7: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'autoSizeTextType' in package 'android'
W:
W: C:\New folder\talalkhan\res\layout\layout_listitem.xml:7: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'autoSizeMinTextSize' in package 'android'
W:
W: C:\New folder\talalkhan\res\layout\layout_listitem.xml:7: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'autoSizeMaxTextSize' in package 'android'
W:
brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec (exit code = 1): [C:\Users\M7303~1.ASH\AppData\Local\Temp\brut_util_Jar_570620229095754242.tmp, p, --forced-package-id, 127, --min-sdk-version, 23, --target-sdk-version, 29, --version-code, 1, --version-name, 1.0, --no-version-vectors, -F, C:\Users\M7303~1.ASH\AppData\Local\Temp\APKTOOL4023821016856894227.tmp, -0, arsc, -0, META-INF/android.support.design_material.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.appcompat_appcompat.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.arch.core_core-runtime.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.asynclayoutinflater_asynclayoutinflater.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.cardview_cardview.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.coordinatorlayout_coordinatorlayout.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.core_core.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.cursoradapter_cursoradapter.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.customview_customview.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.documentfile_documentfile.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.drawerlayout_drawerlayout.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.fragment_fragment.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.gridlayout_gridlayout.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.interpolator_interpolator.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.legacy_legacy-support-core-ui.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.legacy_legacy-support-core-utils.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.legacy_legacy-support-v4.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-livedata-core.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-livedata.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-runtime.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-viewmodel.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.loader_loader.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.localbroadcastmanager_localbroadcastmanager.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.media_media.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.print_print.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.recyclerview_recyclerview.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.slidingpanelayout_slidingpanelayout.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.swiperefreshlayout_swiperefreshlayout.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.transition_transition.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.vectordrawable_vectordrawable-animated.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.vectordrawable_vectordrawable.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.versionedparcelable_versionedparcelable.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.viewpager_viewpager.version, -0, META-INF/com.google.android.material_material.version, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_cab_background_top_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_list_divider_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_list_focused_holo.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_list_longpressed_holo.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_list_pressed_holo_light.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_scrubber_primary_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_scrubber_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/notification_bg_low_normal.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/notification_bg_low_pressed.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/notification_bg_normal.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/notification_bg_normal_pressed.9.png, -0, res/drawable-ldrtl-hdpi-v17/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-ldrtl-mdpi-v17/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-ldrtl-xhdpi-v17/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-ldrtl-xxhdpi-v17/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-ldrtl-xxxhdpi-v17/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_cab_background_top_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_list_divider_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_list_focused_holo.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_list_longpressed_holo.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_list_pressed_holo_light.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_scrubber_primary_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_scrubber_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/notification_bg_low_normal.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/notification_bg_low_pressed.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/notification_bg_normal.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/notification_bg_normal_pressed.9.png, -0, webp, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_cab_background_top_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_list_divider_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_list_focused_holo.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_list_longpressed_holo.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_list_pressed_holo_light.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_scrubber_primary_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_scrubber_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, jpg, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/hwbutton_big_bg_filled_disable.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/hwbutton_big_bg_filled_normal.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/hwbutton_big_bg_filled_pressed.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/hwbutton_big_bg_stroked.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/notification_bg_low_normal.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/notification_bg_low_pressed.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/notification_bg_normal.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/notification_bg_normal_pressed.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_cab_background_top_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_list_divider_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_list_focused_holo.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_list_longpressed_holo.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_list_pressed_holo_light.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_scrubber_primary_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_scrubber_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/hwbutton_big_bg_filled_disable.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/hwbutton_big_bg_filled_normal.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/hwbutton_big_bg_filled_pressed.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/hwbutton_big_bg_stroked.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/hwbutton_big_bg_filled_disable.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/hwbutton_big_bg_filled_normal.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/hwbutton_big_bg_filled_pressed.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/hwbutton_big_bg_stroked.9.png, -0, mp4, -0, arsc, -I, C:\Users\M. Ashir\AppData\Local\apktool\framework\1.apk, -S, C:\New folder\talalkhan\res, -M, C:\New folder\talalkhan\AndroidManifest.xml]
```